# Select camera programatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, camera

My program should select three cameras and take pictures with each of it.

I have the following code at the moment:

```
def getCamera(camera):
    graph = FilterGraph()
    print("Camera List: ")
    print(graph.get_input_devices())

    #tbd get right Camera

    try:
        device = graph.get_input_devices().index("HD Pro Webcam C920")
    except ValueError as e:
        device = graph.get_input_devices().index("Integrated Webcam")
    return device
```

The code above worked fine. But I have three similar cameras with the same name.

Output of this:

```
graph = FilterGraph()
print("Camera List: ")
print(graph.get_input_devices())
```

Is a list with three cameras all the same name. I thought they are in an array and I can select them with this:

```
device = graph.get_input_devices().index(0)
```

Like any other Array.

But I only can access with the Name. Like in the first code example.

How can I access the cameras with index?

Comment: Would probably be helpful if you tag or mention the library where the `FilterGraph` comes from.

Comment: As you say that you can access it by its name it is probably a dictionary. Dictionaries usually do not preserve the order so you cannot access it by index. However depending on your python version you could try to use indexing access with square brackets.

Comment: I user python 3.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the index of the camera in the list to select it. For example, if you want to select the first camera in the list, you can use the following code:

```
device = graph.get_input_devices().index("HD Pro Webcam C920")
```

To select the second camera:

```
device = graph.get_input_devices().index("HD Pro Webcam C920", 1)
```

And to select the third camera, you can use:

```
device = graph.get_input_devices().index("HD Pro Webcam C920", 2)
```

The second argument in the **index()** method specifies the starting index for the search.

You can also modify your **getCamera()** function to take an argument that specifies the index of the camera you want to use:

```
def getCamera(camera_index):
    graph = FilterGraph()
    cameras = graph.get_input_devices()
    if camera_index >= len(cameras):
        raise ValueError("Camera index out of range")
    return cameras[camera_index]

for i in range(3):
    camera = getCamera(i)
    #Do something with it
```

Comment: Looks good. First test works. I will do some tests

Comment: This is the right answer. What I did in the past is create a dictionary with the camera indeces or a normal description as keys and the camera object as value. To keep track of the incoming feed per camera it might be useful to create a custom camera class.

Answer (score 0):

The **graph.get_input_devices()** returns a list.

Like any list, you can always access an index with the bracket notation [ ]

[image]

So if you have 3 cameras as you stated, you can always do **graph.get_input_devices()[0]** or **graph.get_input_devices()[2]** for the 1 and 3rd item in the list

If any one is curious, this is from the [pygrabber](https://pypi.org/project/pygrabber/) module

Comment: Thats What I also tried. that does not work.